# Attempting to output to a text box with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a communications generator that will standardise SMS communications regarding critical IT incidents for my company.  I've got an IF/ELSE statement that identifies whether an issue is new, updated, or resolved to pull the necessary information together and format it accordingly.  As far as I can tell, everything here is fine, however I'm having an issue writing to a text box ('smsToSend') which should allow the user to review before they copy the text across to our sms sender app, as nothing is being output into this box.

```
function generateSMS(){
 var issueTitle = document.getElementById("incidentTitle");
 var advisorImpact = document.getElementById("advisorImpact";
 var incidentUpdate = document.getElementById("incidentUpdate");
 var incidentStatus = document.getElementById("incidentState");
 var startTime = document.getElementById("startTime");
 var endTime = document.getElementById("endTime");
 var incidentPriority = document.getElementById("incidentPriority");
 var incidentBrand = "TechTeam";
 var systemImpacted = document.getElementById("systemImpacted");
 var incidentReference = document.getElementById("incidentReference");

 var smsToSend = document.getElementById("smsToSend");

 if (incidentStatus != "Closed"){
     smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT RESOLVED: " + systemImpacted + ": " + incidentUpdate + ": Start: " + startTime + " End: " + endTime + " Reference: " + incidentReference;
}
else{
     if (incidentUpdate == "We are investigating this issue"){
         smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT ISSUE: " + systemImpacted + ": " + issueTitle + ". " + advisorImpact + ": " + incidentReference;
     }
     else {
         smsToSend = "P" + incidentPriority + " " + incidentBrand + "IT UPDATE: " + systemImpacted + ": " + incidentUpdate + ": " + incidentReference;
     }
 }

}
generateSMS();
alert.getElementById(smsToSend);
```

Comment: What kind of element is `smsToSend`?

Comment: That just looks wrong... Shouldn't you be using `.value` to assign the text box values? Also, you're just overwriting the `smsToSend` variable in your condition blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing all assignments to `smsToSend` like this:

```
smsToSend = yourValue;
```

With this:

```
smsToSend.value = yourValue;
```

Your problem happens because `smsToSend` is an instance of an element, rather than a variable linked to the displayed text. To update the element's value, you have to change the `value` property of the element.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm still not getting any output from this - I've set up the alert message at the bottom of the code, however this is returning 'undefined variable' when i'm attempting to use it with either of the following:

alert.getElementById(smsToSend); 

alert.(smsToSend); 

and if I use " " then it outputs just "smsToSend" in the alert box.

Comment: You get `undefined` when you call `alert(smsToSend.value)`?

Comment: I'm testing it in jshint and it's saying that the smsToSend is an undefined variable - similarly when i'm trying it on the webpage i'm embedding this code to it's not outputting anything to the text box element with the id smsToSend

Comment: Have you checked if your HTML element actually has the id "smsToSend"?

Comment: I have the following element in the HTML: 
`<input id="smsToSend" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 60px;"/>`

Comment: It's a scope problem. You declare `smsToSend` inside your function but alert it outside. Move the alert into the function

Answer (score 1):

The Right way of setting the value to a text box is

```
var smsToSend = document.getElementById("smsToSend");

smsToSend.value = "Your value";
```